# Superposición de elementos

Tags: html, css

vengo con un problema que estoy teniendo con css, estoy utilizando razor pages de asp net
Estoy haciendo un ejercicio sobre un catalogo de autos!
El problema que tengo es que al agregar cierta cantidad de divs se me superponen con un botón y con el pie de página

CSS del boton:

```
#btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    
    display: block;
}
```

CSS de los DIV (las publicaciones de los autos)

```
#container {
    border: 10px outset #cccccc;
    text-align: center;
    width: 170px;
    height: 353px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 8px;
   

}

#container2 {
    background-color: black;
    
}
```

foto de la pagina:

[https://i.imgur.com/fB3dbSo.jpg[![introducir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGr49.jpg) la descripción de la imagen aquí][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B2U8.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B2U8.jpg)

Muchas gracias

EDIT:

CODIGO HTML:

```
    var listado = Model.lista.obtenerAutos();

    if (listado.Count == 0)
    {
        <p>No se encuentran publicaciones cargadas actualmente</p>
    }
    else
    {


        foreach (var item in listado)
        {
            <div id="container">
                <div id="container2">
                    <img src="@item.url" width="150" height="150">
                    <p class="info" id="p">Marca: @item.marca</p>
                    <p class="info">Modelo: @item.modelo</p>
                    <p class="info">Año: @item.año</p>
                    <p class="info">KM: @item.km</p>
                    <a href="Detalle?id=@item.id">
                    
                    <p class="info2">Detalle</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

    }


}
<div id="btn">
<a href="Nuevo">
    <button>Nueva publicación</button>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: seguramente es porque el boton tiene la propiedad position: absolute, si tiene esa propiedad el elemento se posicionara con respecto al elemento padre y no tendra un espacio reservado en el documento, por lo que puede superponerse a otros elementos si lo usas mal. Una posicion absoluta sirve si queres que un elemento ocupe una posicion muy especifica, pero si agregas mas elementos entonces se van a superponer.

Comment: si no tiene un elemento padre entonces se posicionara con respecto al body, osea al documento en si

Comment: Ahi se me dejaron de superponer, gracias. Pero ahora se pone al costado, yo quiero que siempre el botón este abajo de todo!! y lo del pie de pagina sabes que puede ser?? gracias!! está asi por ahora https://imgur.com/fpOL2gv

Comment: pone el html tambien, lo que podes hacer es que cada vez que quieras agregar un div ese sea insertado siempre antes del boton y el pie de pagina, con respecto al pie este no tiene formato y no tengo manera de saber como esta posicionado, pon todo tu codigo.

Comment: ahi agregue el html, tiene c# tambien porque es razor